# Using mvc-mini-profiler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm trying to use the mvc-mini-profiler with EFCodeFirst I'm creating a DbProfiledConnection and passing it to the DbContext on construction as below.  The application continues to work as expected by the sql is not exposed to the Profiler.

```
public class WebContext : DbContext
{
    static DbConnection _connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebContext"].ConnectionString);
    static DbConnection _profiledConnection = MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbConnection.Get(_connection);        

    public WebContext()
            : base(_profiledConnection, true)
    {   

    }
```

oops my bad.

I've modified it so that when my WebContext is constructed in my UnitOfWork i pass in a ProfiledDbConnection

```
public UnitOfWork()
{             
    var profiledConnection = MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbConnection.Get(connection);
    this.context = new MyContext(profiledConnection);
}
```

I've checked and MiniProfier Current has been set in Application_BeginRequest and it returns a ProfiledDbConnection when I then try and query the database an error is thrown in the ProfiledDbProviderServices class.

```
 protected override string GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
 {
     return tail.GetProviderManifestToken(connection);
 }
```

this method returns a "The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string." error

Comment: btw, a static connection is dangerous - it should be request-specific.

Comment: Why is a static connection dangerous? Also, am I actually using a static context if I initiate a new context only at the top of my controller and not in each request?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I *suspect* this relates to the static field initializer. Connections on web apps should *never* be static anyway (but request-specific at most).

The key is: what does `ProfiledDbConnection` actually come out as? The `Get` method returns a `ProfiledDbConnection` only if you are currently profiling (on the current request), and the connection is profiled against the `MiniProfiler` instance on that request.

If you use a static field, then there are two scenarios:

- the static field is initialized *without* a request context (or a non-developer request context): no profiling will occur as `MiniProfiler.Current` is null
- the static field is initialized, but everything is logged against the **very first** request, which is quickly dead

Comment: A big +1. There's little point in profiling a app with a static context reference. You can tell just by looking that it will have problems!

Comment: oops my bad. I've changed my code but am now getting a token exception in ProfiledDbProviderServices

Comment: @feanz ah right; ok, EF codefirst isn't a tool I use, so I haven't validated that scenario. However, we've had (today) a user volunteer a patch for EF code first. Give me a few hours to merge etc

Comment: Let me know when you have applied the patch as I could pull the code and help test it.

Comment: i m having strange problem when using mini profiler with linq to sql please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410756/using-different-overload-of-datacontext-in-linq-to-sql