# How do you use the mvc-mini-profiler with Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-mini-profiler

I am trying to use the mvc-mini-profiler with MVC3 and keep getting the following error

Unable to determine the provider name for connection of type 'MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbConnection'

Below is the code that I am using to try and instatiate my Context.

```
DbConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString);

var profiledConnection = MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbConnection.Get(conn);
return new DB(profiledConnection);
```

And here is the DB Context Class.

```
public class DB:DbContext, Stats.Data.IDB
{
    public DB(DbConnection conn)
        : base(conn, true)
    {

    }...
```

Comment: [A fix is coming RSN.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291727/using-mvc-mini-profiler/6291866#comment-7348880)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I've got the same problem. Thanks

Comment: Simon G. I added a bug and they say that a proposed patch has been submitted but it has not been patched yet, so no luck so far

Comment: Can you try latest, this should all work fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 1.5 this is now supported see: http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler

The step to configure it are listed here: [Using mvc-mini-profiler database profiling with Entity Framework Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550046/using-mvc-mini-profiler-database-profiling-with-entity-framework-code-first/6743941#6743941)