# How can I append information to every SqlCommand emitted by a DbContext?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, mvc-mini-profiler, dbcontext

I am trying to write a module to append a comment containing useful information to every `Linq2Entities` SQL query emitted by an entity framework `DbContext` (the information will be used in debugging).

Using `Linq2Sql`, I had previously accomplished this via extending the MvcMiniProfiler `ProfiledDbCommand` command class. However, I can't get the same approach to work with EF/DbContext. I've extending `EFProfiledDbCommand`, but that doesn't work. Indeed, even a straight use of `EFProfiledDbCommand` doesn't work: I get the error

> Unable to determine the provider name for connection of type
>   'MvcMiniProfiler.Data.EFProfiledDbConnection'.

Can anyone supply either workaround for my current solution or an alternate approach to this problem?

Comment: Hi, have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295802/how-do-you-use-the-mvc-mini-profiler-with-entity-framework-4-1

Comment: You might find the [Entity Framework Tracing Provider](http://nuget.org/packages/CommunityEFProviderWrappers.EFTracingProvider) of interest.

Comment: EFHooks also comes to mind: http://www.mcdev.za.net/efhooks-project/

Answer (score 1):

It appears the answer is in the comment by @Giorgio: [How do you use the mvc-mini-profiler with Entity Framework 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295802/how-do-you-use-the-mvc-mini-profiler-with-entity-framework-4-1) and [Using mvc-mini-profiler database profiling with Entity Framework Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550046/using-mvc-mini-profiler-database-profiling-with-entity-framework-code-first/6743941#6743941) and is most easily solved by adding `MiniProfiler.EF` NuGet package.