# Using different overload of DataContext in Linq-to-SQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, datacontext, mvc-mini-profiler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help Configure mvc mini profiler with Linq to Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422213/help-configure-mvc-mini-profiler-with-linq-to-sql)

We have been using Linq-to-SQL for db persistence. Previously, I was instantiating my `DataContext` in my repositories like this:

```
DbContext db = new DbContext();
```

Now that I want to profile my database using mvc mini profiler, I have used [the following approach](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/) for creating the `DataContext` object

```
partial class DBContext
{
   public static DBContext Get()
   {
      var conn = ProfiledDbConnection.Get(new SqlConnection(connectionString));
      return new DBContext(conn);
   }
}
```

I get `DataContext` object nice and fine but when I run Linq queries against this object it gives me null reference exception at methods which were working fine previously. Any ideas why it is behaving this way?
**Edit:** Ok this is the liqn query which is giving me the null reference exception

```
var val = (from mod in db.sysModules
                        where
                        mod.ModuleActionResult.ToLower().Equals(actionName.ToLowerInvariant())
                    select mod).SingleOrDefault();
```

please note that its not db which is null but Expanding the sysModules actually throws the exception. Look at the following screen shot
[image]
when i tried to expand sysmodules in result view here it gives null reference exception. When i instantiated DataContext using new keyword everything works fine.
**Edit2:** The exception is being thrown at MiniPofiler.cs on AddSqlTiming method. plz have a look at stack trace
[image]

Comment: has it something to do with data load options. i m setting data load options in my base controller

Comment: Can you post an example where you try and use this and get the error?

Comment: @Badger posted the code where i get null reference exception. Its not only place where i get such exception though

Comment: There is another table property oaMemo, when i hit it first time it behaves as expected but when i navigate away and come back again it also gives me null reference exception. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems to be a bug in the mini profiler. You might want to contact the mini profiler developers for further assistance.

Comment: @Adrian Gigore thanks for reply. i think the same way and i have created an issue at their site on google code