# How to configure mvc mini profiler with Linq to SQL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, datacontext, mvc-mini-profiler

I have configured mini profiler with asp.net mvc application. I also want to profile my db so I hooked it with L2S datacontext as in [this example](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/).

It is working fine for some queries but on other queries I find null reference exception. When I attached the source code to debug I found out that

```
 internal void AddSqlTiming(SqlTiming stats)
        {
            Head.AddSqlTiming(stats);
        }
```

`Head` Property in above method is null in MiniProfiler.cs at line 198. Any idea why?

**EDIT:** Following method returns me the datacontext object

```
public static EvoletDataContext Get() 
        {
            var connection = ProfiledDbConnection.Get(new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["evoletworksConnectionString"].ToString()));
            //var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["evoletworksConnectionString"].ToString());
            //return new EvoletDataContext(connection);
            return DataContextUtils.CreateDataContext<EvoletDataContext>(connection);
        }
```

And below is the query on which miniprofiler crashes for the first time

```
public sysModule GetModuleHead(string actionName)
        {
            var val =  (from mod in db.sysModules
                        where
                        mod.ModuleActionResult.ToLower().Equals(actionName.ToLowerInvariant())
                    select mod).SingleOrDefault();
            return val;


        }
```

For more detail, please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410756/using-different-overload-of-datacontext-in-linq-to-sql) as well. I tried but failed to reproduce problem in demo project.

**Edit 2:** Here is the stacktrace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   MvcMiniProfiler.MiniProfiler.AddSqlTiming(SqlTiming stats) in C:\Dev\mvc-mini-profiler\MvcMiniProfiler\MiniProfiler.cs:241
   MvcMiniProfiler.SqlTiming..ctor(DbCommand command, ExecuteType type, MiniProfiler profiler) in C:\Dev\mvc-mini-profiler\MvcMiniProfiler\SqlTiming.cs:66
   MvcMiniProfiler.SqlProfiler.ExecuteStartImpl(DbCommand command, ExecuteType type) in C:\Dev\mvc-mini-profiler\MvcMiniProfiler\SqlProfiler.cs:50
   MvcMiniProfiler.SqlProfilerExtensions.ExecuteStart(SqlProfiler sqlProfiler, DbCommand command, ExecuteType type) in C:\Dev\mvc-mini-profiler\MvcMiniProfiler\SqlProfiler.cs:95
   MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) in C:\Dev\mvc-mini-profiler\MvcMiniProfiler\Data\ProfiledDbCommand.cs:149
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader() +12
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult) +724
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries) +189
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query) +659
   System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +59
   System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source) +265
   UserManagement.Models.FilterRepository.GetModuleHead(String actionName) in D:\Evolet\UserManagement\UserManagement\Models\FilterRepository.cs:14
   UserManagement.Models.DummyAttrib.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) in D:\Evolet\UserManagement\UserManagement\Models\Filters.cs:30
   Glimpse.Net.Plumbing.GlimpseAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +149
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +830
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +135
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +232
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +68
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +140
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +61
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +110
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +690
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +194
```

Comment: Some kind of code example would be useful here

Comment: and the exact same query works w/o mini-profiler? Can I check, then, is `db` non-null? and `actionName`? If these are non-null, can you perhaps include the `StackTrace` from the `Exception`, so I can see where it is coming froM?

Comment: yeh without mini-profiler its working. db and actionname are not null either. in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410756/using-different-overload-of-datacontext-in-linq-to-sql i have included stacktrace of the exception but i m afraid picture is pretty compressed by SO

Comment: just include the text ;p

Comment: never thought of pasting the text directly :O

Comment: @Muhammed weekend - have been busy with, like, life

Comment: @Marc have good time. thanks for replying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This used to happen if you had a `ProfiledDbConnection` in play and the actual profiler was set to null.

In general we avoid serving our internal consumers a `ProfiledDbConnection` if the current request is not profiled ... this means everything is just a bit faster.

Unfortunately, this can be sometimes tricky to do with EF and L2S. To overcome this I just checked in a change that allows you to use the Profiling bespoke objects even if no profiler is in play.

Nonetheless, my recommendation remains that you should be using raw connections where possible when you are not profiling.

Comment: Has anyone tried with the latest version? It seems like the issue still exists.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same behavior even now. I'm just pulling the `Update-Package MiniProfiler` from nuget.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell you are going to need to grab latest from google code

Comment: ah, gotcha... any chance it'll make it's way to nuget?

Comment: @ChaseFlorell the plan is to do another release soon, we want to break all the namespaces cause the MVC thingy is misleading.

Comment: Still exists in 1.9. At least when trying to inject a dependency into a custom RoleProvider. Not sure why the request isn't profiled, it should be. I think something isn't init correctly yet, maybe structuremap.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this issue has finally been fixed in the latest commit:

https://github.com/SamSaffron/MiniProfiler/commit/bcea578dd47d7f9ccf1f495cf67c360cdece5f2a